Android NFC Intermittent IsoDep
0
When testing NFC reader/HCE scenario, I am having intermittent issue with IsoDep tag technology suddenly stop being detected on a tag scan. I have checked and read following post:
How can I reconnect to IsoDep tag?
My issue seems a bit different because I do not have a connection issue. I am always able to read the tag. my issue is that the HCE tag read by the Reader is not having IsoDep technology after multiple reads.
Here is my scenario:
Phone 1 = Pixel 3XL API 31, acting as NFC reader
Phone 2 = Pixel 7 API 34, acting as HCE (so this phone is the tag)
When phone 2 is tapped against phone1, Phone1 discovered the tag (OnTagDiscoved is fired). The discovered tag technologies contain NfcA and IsoDep, and I am able to proceed to send APDU commands between the two phones.
Now after multiple testing iterations, IsoDep stops being detected and the tag discovered only list NfcA. It is like something got disabled or turned off on the Phone 2 preventing IsoDep technology to be available anymore on phone 2. even after restart/reboot of both phones, IsoDep is not being available.
When I flipped the phone roles (Phone 1 as HCE and Phone 2 as Reader), I do not experience the issue (at least not so far).
I will keep investigating this but does anyone know what might cause IsoDep technology to suddenly stop being detected when the HCE phone is tapped to the Reader phone?
Ak
Andoid NFC Reader/ HCE scenrio
